# Proving that removing unreachable states from $M$ does not change $L(M)$

Tags: automata, finite-automata

What is the idea behind proving that:

> Removing **unreachable states** from a DFA $M$ does not change $L(M)$.

I don't know what cases I need consider. Consider any $w\in \sum^*$ and then check for the cases $w \in L(M)$ or $w \not \in L(M)$? Then I was thinking that there could some lemmas regarding DFA minimalization, sort of like "Assume DFA not minimal, i.e. contains unreachable states.", then "DFA can be minimalized", then "minimal DFA recognizes the same language".

In checking $w \in L(M)$ or $w \not \in L(M)$ one should find out (as the answer below points out) that, because of the definition for $L(M)$ and unreachable states, $w \in L(M)$ does not depend on unreachable states (since $w \in L(M)$ with reachable states). Therefore, for any $w \in L(M)$, it's recognised by both the DFA with and without unreachable states. Is this enough?

Comment: Not every proof proceeds by case distinction -- but sure, the two cases you have identified seems reasonable. And then? (You should add these clarifications to your question; click in on the "edit" link!)

Comment: Why the down voting?

Comment: Ad proof idea: yes, obviously (?) that's what you have to do. You have rephrased the claim (correctly). In order to rigorously prove this, you'll have to give an accepting computation for the modified automaton for ever $w \in L(M)$ (that's just unfolding the definition of $L(M')$). A similar unfolding leads to what you have to show for $w \not\in L(M)$ (all computations...).

Comment: ad downvotes: apparently people agreed with my first comment. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/751/98). (Sorry, that link should have been in that first comment.) FWIW, I retracted my downvote now that you  added some more of your own thoughts. It's still thin, but no longer a pure problem dump.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not a word $w$is in $L$ depends on the sequence of states the automaton passes through when it reads $w$ (specifically, it depends on whether that sequence ends in an accepting state or not). If you have a state $q$ that's never reached, for any input, then there is no word $w$ such that the decision of whether $w\in L$ or $w\notin L$ depends on any property of $q$, or even its existence.